Dex-Protector - How to Troubleshoot Log Errors using the log file?
I’m using Dex-Protector to protect my APK files approaching with different key-stores, but I’ve been running into some errors during the process. Dex-Protector generates log files, but I’m not entirely sure how to interpret them to figure out what’s going wrong. Specifically, I’m having trouble with key-store issues (like password problems, missing keys, or alias errors), and I’m also wondering if there are any issues with encryption or obfuscation that might be causing problems. On top of that, I’m not sure how to verify that the APK is being signed correctly, and I’m seeing some runtime errors after protection. Can anyone help me understand what kind of log messages or errors I should be looking for to troubleshoot these issues? Any advice on how to dig into the logs and fix key-store, encryption, signing, or runtime issues would be really appreciated...
Need to know how to use the log file , what are the possible things to do with the log file
